# VSS Restore Source Path Too Long Error

Tags: windows-server-2008, vss

I'm trying to restore some files, that were accidently deleted by a user, using the restore previous versions functionality of 2k8r2.  I can see the previous version just fine however no matter how I try and restore them -same location, new location, copying - I get an error stating that the source path is too long. Any ideas on a way around this?

Comment: What is the *exact* error message including any numbers you may get?

Answer (score 1):

This would be a limitation of windows itself, still. It's because VSS appends (yesterday, Date..., Time...) to the end of the folder path, so when trying to restore from it you get errors.

I havnen't found a way around this yet. Actually this is the only post I've seen on the net about this issue (surprising).

Did you find anything out to get around this? Might as well have it documented here if there is a solution.

Comment: In my case, I had to revert to tape to get this to actually restore. I tried sharing down as far as I could go, but in this case the document names were just too long still. So this would be a partial user issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought.  If you share the folder containing the deleted content, and then access the directory via the share (i.e.: making the path short), does PV work?

Answer (score 0):

Sharing/mapping doesn't work, it will just say that the system could not find the folder specified. If anyone has any other ideas, I am also listening!  I have it down to the folder, I used the properties of the folder in Previous Versions to be able to browse, the problem is you still can't pull it out of the folder, my next step is to try it out of safemode to see if I can rename some of the folders to make it work.